# Combine SQL queries, joining tables based on a calculation

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I am trying to make my SQL more elegant and/or reduce the number of queries I need to run. I have a set of two queries:

1. The first query affects my original table, updating an abbreviation
   record with information from a description record.
2. The second query
   joins a secondary table to the original table based on the
   abbreviation record.

Is there any way to write these as a single
    query?

**Simplified Query 1:**

```
UPDATE [tblManipulateD]
SET [tblManipulateD].[abbreviation] = RIGHT([tblManipulateD].[description],3)
WHERE [tblManipulateD].[description] LIKE “*abbrev:*";
```

**Simplified Query 2**

```
UPDATE [tblManipualteD]
LEFT JOIN [tblStorage] ON ([tblManipulateD].[abbreviation] = [tblStorage].[storage abbreviation]
SET [tblManipualteD].[product code] = [tblStorage].[storage product]
WHERE [tblManipulateD].[description] LIKE “*abbrev:*";
```

Again, I am wondering if there is a way (in one query) to join a secondary table to a main table based off of a calculation from the main table. I appreciate your help and/or insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can join on those last 3 characters of the description column:

```
UPDATE [tblManipulateD]
SET [tblManipulateD].[abbreviation] = RIGHT([tblManipulateD].[description],3), 
    [tblManipualteD].[product code] = [tblStorage].[storage product]
FROM [tblManipulateD] 
LEFT JOIN [tblStorage] ON RIGHT([tblManipulateD].[description],3) = [tblStorage].[storage abbreviation]
WHERE [tblManipulateD].[description] LIKE “*abbrev:*";
```

Comment: MS Access doesn't like the syntax for the `UPDATE` query. After trying your syntax directly, I tried putting the `LEFT JOIN` line directly after the `UPDATE` line, and removing the `FROM` line so that it matched the syntax of some queries I have already written that do work. Unfortunately, neither attempt worked. 

Do you have any other ideas? Maybe MS Access can't handle this type of operation.

Comment: Oh my goodness... my problem was some spelling errors! I was able to get your code to work (joining on the last three characters of the description column), but I did have to re-jigger the join phrase around like I mentioned above. Thank you very much!